# Wordpress 3.1.2 dropdown menu & Android

Tags: android, wordpress

The Wordpress 3.1.2 dropdown menu of the default theme "twentyten" works fine on an iPhone, but not on Android. It does not "drop down" when you touch the menu.

Does anyone have a workaround for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally ended up "animating" the WP menu with jQuery, and making it react to clicks, instead of the CSS:hover selector. Now it works fine on every platform: Android, iPhone, iPad, IE7/8, Opera, Safari, Chrome and Firefox.